# Vb.Net Add table to dataset and send it to an other form

Tags: vb.net, forms, dataset, addition

I have an application that loads cars data from sql server database as follows.

```
sql = " select car.*, (model + ' -- ' + plateNo) as selectCar from car"
daAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConn)
daAdapter.Fill(dsDataset, "car")
```

So data would look like the following:

[image]

Then instead of loading distinct values of brand from database I have created one datatable to get the distinct values of the brand. And then add it to the dataset as follows:

```
tblBrand = New DataTabl
tblBrand = dsDataset.Tables("car").DefaultView.ToTable(True, "brand")
tblBrand.TableName = "brand"
dsDataset.Tables.Add(tblBrand)
```

Actually I use this brand table to display the filter options in the brand combobx without any problem.

What I need is that when I press the add button I go to an other form and I want to use this brand options in the other form. So when I click the add button I have the following code:

```
Dim newCar As New frmCar(dsDataset)
carMode = "new"
newCar.ShowDialog()
```

And I created a constructor in the frmCar form as follows:

```
Sub New(ByVal dsOptions)
    InitializeComponent()

    Try
       cmbBrand.DataSource = dsOptions.table("brand")
       cmbBrand.DisplayMember = "brand"
       cmbBrand.ValueMember = "brand"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
    End Try
End Sub
```

But the following error pops up:

```
Public member 'table' on type 'DataSet' not found.
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to turn both [option strict and explicit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329) `On`. This will prevent you from doing these kinds of mistakes in the future.

The error is quite self-explainable. A `DataSet` doesn't have a public member (property, method etc..) named `table`.

All you have to do is change:

```
Sub New(ByVal dsOptions)
    cmbBrand.DataSource = dsOptions.table("brand")
```

to:

```
Sub New(ByVal dsOptions As DataSet)
    cmbBrand.DataSource = dsOptions.Tables("brand")
```

Comment: Additionally, Intellisense should be showing the error in the code and be able to provide the correction.  no mystery.

Comment: All right, that really solves the problem. Thank you Mr. Roger.